# FTP or any others way?I just need guideline

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

Actually I'm now have the basic skill in FTP only, and now I'm facing the problem of getting `.log` file from a remote site. I can access into it, and check for the file exist, but don't know how to retrieve it.

1. Can I use `apache FileUtils` to set `source` and `destination`? If can, can I set the destination to another remote site? (like put ip address)
2. Or can I use File `input` and `output` stream? and the same, can i apply ip address in the outputstream?

or any others suggestion for me?
thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java FTP libraries you can use: [JavaWorld FTP libs article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html?page=1)